# Lewis structure and resonance for arginine ion

Tags: resonance, lewis-structure

I'm working through a problem set in MIT's open courseware 'Principles of Chemical Science' course [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/5-111sc-principles-of-chemical-science-fall-2014/resources/mit5_111f14_lec10prob/). In question 5, it asks:

> The skeletal structures of two amino acids, leucine and arginine, are drawn below. Non-zero formal charges are indicated. Provide the Lewis structure(s), including double bonds and lone pairs, for each of these molecules. If there are equivalent resonance forms (which may include moving the formal charge on N), include them

This arginine structure is given for part (b):

[image: arginine ion structure]

I've been able to produce the resonance structures given in the solution sheet ([here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/5-111sc-principles-of-chemical-science-fall-2014/resources/mit5_111f14_lec10soln/)).

[image: arginine solutions]

But I've also produced another resonance structure which I think is valid but it was not included in the solutions. I've put the formal charge on on the non-terminal N atom. My structure seems to satisfy the octet rule for all atoms and has the same number of bonds and electron pairs as the other solutions. Is there something I'm missing here?

[image: my additional]

Comment: Your third structure is correct. In fact it is more stable than the other two structures because of inductive effect.

Comment: As it is mentioned in the question , you have to produce "equivalent" canonical structures   only. Your third structure is not equivalent to the other two but the both above are equivalent w.r.t each other.

Comment: The first given skeletal arg with formal charge is not correct.

Comment: @CHEMUMAN can you explain what is meant by 'equivalence'? Why is moving the charge between terminal N's equivalent while the third structure is not?

Comment: @AlRi The two structures are structurally equivalent as you cannot distinguish them without numbering the terminal N atoms. Equivalent canonical structures have same stabilities and same contribution to the 'Resonance Hybrid'. Your third structure is obviously not equivalent to the other two as you can easily distinguish it from the other two just by the sight , moreover if you analyze the three structures chemically , you will land on to the conclusion that the third structure has different stability. E.g.: Often you draw two "equivalent" Kekulé structures (canonical form) for Benzene.

Comment: @AlRi Moreover there are no equivalent structures for your third structure.                                       For better insights refer to :https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Organic_Chemistry_I_(Cortes)/04%3A_Lewis_Formulas_Structural_Isomerism_and_Resonance_Structures/4.03%3A_Resonance_Structures

Comment: @AlRi For future reference: two, or more of mesomeric formulae are put into a single pair of square brackets *in common*.  It doesn't make sense to enclose each form into its own pair of square brackets.  As an example, see the depiction of the nitrite anion in Wikipedia's article [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resonance_(chemistry)).

Comment: Thanks for the responses @CHEMUMAN. It is making more sense to me now. My third structure is valid, but not structurally equivalent to the given skeletal arginine. The question is asking specifically for equivalent structures, so only two structures are shown in the answer.

Comment: @Buttonwood thanks for letting me know, that image was copied out of the MIT answer sheet.